Find users pairs who have no mutual friends
I have a table that records some user pairs. Each row indicates that the two users are friends.



user_id1
user_id2




1
3


1
5


2
4


2
5


3
5


4
5


6
7


8
9



I want to find all pairs of users who are friends with each other and have no mutual friends and I tried:
SELECT f1.user_id1, f1.user_id2
FROM Friends f1
LEFT JOIN Friends f2 ON (f1.user_id1 = f2.user_id1 AND f1.user_id2 <> f2.user_id2) OR (f1.user_id1 = f2.user_id2 AND f1.user_id2 <> f2.user_id1)
WHERE f2.user_id1 IS NULL AND f2.user_id2 IS NULL
ORDER BY f1.user_id1, f1.user_id2;

I got right answer:



user_id1
user_id2




6
7


8
9



But when I added a new row (3,6) to the table, I got the wrong result:



user_id1
user_id2




8
9



The correct result at this time should be:



user_id1
user_id2




3
6


6
7


8
9



Can someone give me a correct way?(By the way, I use PieCloudDB Database)

What I mean is that if A and B are friends, and C is friends with both A and B, then A and B have a mutual friend C. I want to find all pairs of users who have no mutual friends.

I don't know what pieclouddb is, but I think the following query will work for most RDBMS.(I tested in PostgreSQL and got the answer you expected)
with a as (
    select user_id1 u1, user_id2 u2 from friends
    union all
    select user_id2 u1, user_id1 u2 from friends
)
select user_id1,user_id2
from friends
where not exists(
    (select u2 from a where u1 = user_id1)
     intersect
    (select u2 from a where u1 = user_id2)
)
order by user_id1,user_id2;

